# Swapping a existing topology with a new one

Tags: apache-storm

I have added new bolts in my storm topology and want to swap the existing topology with the new one.How can i achieve it in such a way that when the second topology starts it does not read the same messages again.

Comment: What is your data source?

Comment: I am using kafka as data source.

Comment: See here: https://github.com/apache/storm/tree/master/external/storm-kafka#how-kafkaspout-stores-offsets-of-a-kafka-topic-and-recovers-in-case-of-failures

Comment: @MatthiasJ.Sax : Even after keeping the same zkroot and id kafka reads from the beginning.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're reading from Kafka using the Storm provided Kafka Spout, it stores its offset in Zookeeper. If you keep the id defined in [SpoutConfig](https://github.com/apache/storm/blob/master/external/storm-kafka/src/jvm/storm/kafka/SpoutConfig.java) the same, every time the Kafka Spout restarts it should check Zookeeper and restart from the last committed offset. Achieving your goal of not reading the same messages again.

Comment: Even after passing the same id ,the topology starts reading the data from the beginning.

Comment: This is my code snippet.

`private static KafkaSpout tEmitter(String topic) {
  
  ZkHosts zkHosts = new ZkHosts(zkHostPort);

  SpoutConfig spoutCfg = new SpoutConfig(zkHosts, topic, zkRoot,
    zkSpoutId);
  spoutCfg.scheme = new SchemeAsMultiScheme(new StringScheme());
  KafkaSpout kafkaSpout = new KafkaSpout(spoutCfg);
  
  return kafkaSpout;

 }`